# JQuery: Identify duplicate values in a table textbox column and highlight the textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery and I'm sure this is pretty simple stuff but I was unable to find a solution. I have an employee table with "Number" column which is editable(text box). I want to find the duplicates in the "Number" column and highlight those textboxes. For example in the table below I want to highlight all textboxes with values 10 and 20. Also when a edit is done and there are no longer duplicates, remove the highlight.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1098/)

Any Ideas?

```
<table id="employeeTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>10</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
        <td>20</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>10</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>30</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td>20</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different possibilities, basically you'll have to test if the value of an array exists more than one time, for example like this.

**Update:**
*Using the value selector works fine in the initial state, but it seems that when a value is changed by direct user input  or by calling .val(), the HTML attribute `value` is not changed (only the native JS `.value`). Therefore - to use the value selector in this context, the html value attribute is always updated with the JS .value.*

```
function highlightDuplicates() {
    // loop over all input fields in table
    $('#employeeTable').find('input').each(function() {
        // check if there is another one with the same value
        if ($('#employeeTable').find('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1) {
            // highlight this
            $(this).addClass('duplicate');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove
            $(this).removeClass('duplicate');
        }
    });
}


$().ready(function() {
    // initial test
    highlightDuplicates();

    // fix for newer jQuery versions!
    // since you can select by value, but not by current val
    $('#employeeTable').find('input').bind('input',function() {
        $(this).attr('value',this.value)
    });

    // bind test on any change event
    $('#employeeTable').find('input').on('input',highlightDuplicates);
});
```

[Updated fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1110/).

Comment: Awesome, that works great. Is there a way to do highlight of duplicates as textbox box value  is being  changed instead of blur. May be tie an event which will be efficient for few hundred rows?

Comment: @user1527762 I am not sure if I get your question right, but you could on('input',function(e){}) instead of blur, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1108/ - a few hundred rows might always be a performance challenge.

Comment: Thanks. Also When I change the last row text box value to 30, it does not highlight the textboxes with value 30 (in this case textboxes on rows 4 and 5)

Comment: @user1527762 I have updated the fiddle and the answer one more time. You are right - there is a neat little problem here. The value="xx" selector does not detect any changes on the html value attribute since there are none, to handle this, the new version sets the attribute each time something is changed.

Comment: @alex.michel, is there a way to do this without using the attribute value and instead use the val(). Like In here is it possible to replace value with val()? if  ($('#employeeTable').find('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1) I donot want to update the value attribute as I use it in other places to check default value?

Comment: @user1527762 the result of val() and value attribute should be the same - not different. Anyway you could copy the value of the input field to a custom data attribute and use that one for the tests. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1114/

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Again!

Comment: Thanks! This is so useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are exactly looking for:

[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dskstkcm/)

**1)** First `for` loop for taking all input values into an array `inpValArr[]`

**2)** Second `for` loop for sorting and **finding out the duplicate** ones.

**3)** Third `for` loop for adding class `.highLight` to duplicate ones.

Now all this is in a function: `inputCheck()` which is called on `DOM Ready` and **after you edit the text field**.

```js
inputCheck();
$("#employeeTable input").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
  inputCheck();
});

function inputCheck() {
  var totalInp = $("#employeeTable input").length;
  var inpValArr = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < totalInp; j++) {
    var inpVal = $("#employeeTable input:eq(" + j + ")").val();
    inpValArr.push(inpVal);
  }

  var sorted_arr = inpValArr.sort();
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inpValArr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  $('#employeeTable input').removeClass('highLight');
  for (var k = 0; k < totalInp; k++) {
    $('#employeeTable :input[value="' + results[k] + '"]').addClass('highLight');
  }
}
```

```css
#employeeTable th,
#employeeTable td {
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#employeeTable th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.highLight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="employeeTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Chris</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You code snippet isn't working as your fiddle works.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily give a class such as 'hasInput' to all td with inputs and then try a .each on all of them and check for value if they are 10 or 20 and then add a class to make them styled as you wish.

html:

```
<table id="employeeTable">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td class="hasInput"><input type="text" value = "10"/></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td class="hasInput"><input type="text" value = "20"/></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td class="hasInput"><input type="text" value = "10"/></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td class="hasInput"><input type="text" value = "30"/></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Chris</td>
    <td class="hasInput"><input type="text" value = "20"/></td>        
</tr>
```

css:

```
#employeeTable th, #employeeTable td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#employeeTable th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.colored {
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$('.hasInput > input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 10 || $(this).val() == 20) {
        $(this).addClass('colored');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1103/)

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
var dupes=[], values=[];;
$('.yellow').removeClass('yellow');
$('#employeeTable td:nth-child(3) input').each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).val(),values) == -1){
        values.push($(this).val());
    }
    else{
        dupes.push($(this).val());
    }
    
});
$('#employeeTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function(){return $.inArray(this.value,dupes) == -1 ? false : true }).addClass('yellow');
```

```css
#employeeTable th, #employeeTable td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#employeeTable th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="employeeTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "10"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "20"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "10"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "30"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "20"/></td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer provided by @axel.michel using `.count()` selector of Linq.js.  I decided to go this route because I couldn't get the JQuery selector to work correctly provided in his answer.  And I really like the Linq.js and find myself loving it more each time i implement a use of it.

```
var allTextBoxes = $().find('input:text');

// loop over all input fields on page
$(allTextBoxes)
    .each(function() {
        // select any other text boxes that have the same value as this one
        if (Enumerable.from(allTextBoxes).count("$.value == '" + $(this).val() + "'") > 1) {
            // If more than 1 have the same value than highlight this textbox and display an error message
            $(this).addClass('duplicate');
            $('#custom-field-validator').html('Custom fields must have unique names.');
            valid = false;
        } else {
            // otherwise remove
            $(this).removeClass('duplicate');
        }
    });
```

This is working fine without needing to worry about the value selector and syncing the value attributes.